# C++ overload operator= for different rhs types, at construction time

Tags: c++, char, operator-overloading

I've written a class `Tag` that holds tags as strings and allows operations to be done on it. For ease of use I'm overloading the `operator=` for string-like types. What I've got so far:

```
Tag& Tag::operator=(const std::string& rhs)
{
    setTag(rhs);
    return *this;
}

Tag& Tag::operator=(const char* rhs)
{
     setTag(rhs);
     return *this;
}
```

(where `setTag()` is overloaded for `std::string` and `char`). Most of the usage is covered by this:

```
 Tag tag1 = std::string("lala");
 Tag tag2;
 tag2 = std::string("lala2");
 Tag tag3;
 tag3 = "lala";
```

however, the most 'fundamental' one does not compute:

```
 Tag tag4 = "lala";
```

It gives me this error:

```
 conversion from 'const char [5]' to non-scalar type 'Tag' requested
```

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That last one isn't an `operator=()` - you need a constructor that takes a `char const*`.

```
Tag(char const* s);
```

Comment: To elaborate, saying `ClassName objVar = someValue;` invokes a one-parameter constructor (equivalent to `ClassName objVar (someValue);`), whereas using the = after the object has been created invokes an `operator=`.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I never use the assignment syntax for construction.  Also, for all constructors I put a space, such as `MyClass foo (a, b, c)` or `MyClass ( )` to draw attention that it isn't a function call either.  :-/